# programmatically refer to object libraries in mixed microsoft office environment

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

we have a mixed environment. Some workstations have Microsoft Office 2010 installed while others have Microsoft Office 2007 installed. A lot of our in-house developed applications are referring to the Outlook 12.0 object library and the Excel 12.0 object library. In Office 2010 these are referring to the 14.0 object libraries. Is there a way when users launch an Access application that it checks which version of Office they have installed and when it detects either Office 2007 or Office 2010 so that it can programatically set the correct references to the Object Libraries?? Many thanks for any help and/or suggestions.

Comment: Is each workstation using a local version of the client app?

Comment: Yes, each workstation has the ms access application installed on their desktop. We distribute our applications to the workstations using a ClickOnce portal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the references to use the earliest version of the reference and Ms Access will automatically upgrade the reference for later versions of Access if needed.

For example, if none of your workstations use anything less than Access 2007, you should set the reference to Excel 12.0. Any workstation using Access 2010 or 2013 will update the reference automatically for their local copy

Comment: hmmm. interesting I didn't know that it would set it automatically. That's easy :-) - Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar conflict issues between office 2010,2013 and 2016.

I think the whole point of initiating this thread is that "should" <> "does"...
Meaning that programing to the earlier version does not "always" work when the user PC is not running the exact same version of MS Office that was used during development.

I think maybe need to somehow add both object references to the compiled version and then the app can pick.

In other words, I think the development PC needs to be running both versions of Outlook.

You could also alternatively develop the app on a PC running the earlier version and then save off a copy to be compiled in a newer version of office on a different PC. You'd be basically generating versions specifically for each version of Office.